# query ok in shell not in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

this query returns 2 documents in the shell:

```
db.groups.find({_id: { $in: [ObjectId("5b0ac04e6bd3dde1c8afbee9"), ObjectId("5bb5f8dbe3f4ab9a287801fe")]}});
```

but when I pass it to a node app with this code it returns null:

```
getGroupsByIds: ({_ids}) => {
    console.log('_ids: ', _ids);
    // log result: _ids:  [ '5b0ac04e6bd3dde1c8afbee9', '5bb5f8dbe3f4ab9a287801fe' ]
    console.log('isArray? ', Object.prototype.toString.call(_ids) == '[object Array]');
    // log result: isArray?  true
    if( _ids) {
        const inArray = new Array();
        for (let key in _ids){
            console.log('typeof _ids[key]: ', typeof _ids[key]);
            // log result: typeof _ids[key]:  string
            const id = new ObjectId(_ids[key]);
            inArray.push(id);
        }
        console.log('inArray: ', inArray);
        // log result: inArray:  [ 5b0ac04e6bd3dde1c8afbee9, 5bb5f8dbe3f4ab9a287801fe ]
        //-- $in doesn't work
        return  this.db
        .collection(this.collection)
        .find({ _id: {$in: inArray }})
        .toArray()
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

I'm using:
MongoDB client shell version 4.0.3,
MongoDB node.js driver 3.3.2,
node 10.16.0 (also tested with 12.3.1)

Comment: That `isArray?` test is downright worrying. Why not use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)? You can also do `const inArray = [ ]` and save a lot of typing. `new Array()` is only necessary when you need to pass it arguments.

Comment: In the one version you do `find({ _id: ids })` while the other is `find({ _id: { $in: ids } })`. Are you sure that's the right notation?

Comment: thanks for the Array tips, the shell command i also tried with { _id: { $in: [ObjectId("5b0ac04e6bd3dde1c8afbee9"), ObjectId("5bb5f8dbe3f4ab9a287801fe")]} i mistyped it in my question, both work in the shell, both don't in the node app. I'm not shure it's the right notation, the documentation gives no examples of using $in in the nodejs driver. Google didn't help me either.

Comment: correction of the above comment, the find({_id: [ObjectId("5b0ac04e6bd3dde1c8afbee9"), ObjectId("5bb5f8dbe3f4ab9a287801fe")]}) gives no results in the shell either. the version with $in does.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the $in query, i debugged my method (a graphql resolver) by making it async and looking at the result within the method and it returns the expected objects.